# Biber working with style=nature but error with style=chem-acs

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I'm having troubles with the following `.tex` file. 
Using `style=nature` gives me no errors, using `style=chem-acs` or `science` does not work and gives me a bazillion errors (see below).

I run pdfLaTeX, then Biber, then pdfLaTeXagain for the working example

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=nature,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2011}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Errors: 
 Package keyval Error: giveninits undefined.
 Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'name:family-given' undefined
etc
[image: Error log]

**Edit:**

Cause of the error was a mismatch of the biblatex and the biblatex-chem package. Running Update (admin) twice fixed the error.

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles`to your input and copy the resulting `File list` from the `.log` into the question: this is 'works for me' with an up-to-date system.

Comment: The code should work if the versions of Biber, `biblatex` and `biblatex-chem` match. Update your system and try again. If you are using MikTeX run the Updater in both Admin and User modes (you may have to run it twice in each mode to get all updates done). Also delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`. `.bcf`) before you continue.

Comment: Running Update(admin) twice worked. Thank you! I only ran Update when searching for the error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by mismatching installed files